# Visual Basic, cannot pass array of objects to a web service, duplicate classes in both, web service and the client

Tags: vb.net

I have problems trying to pass an array of objects to a asmx webservice. The web service have a class that reads as follow:

```
Public Class DataSyncTransport

Property IdCols As String
Property SyncDataList As New List(Of DataTable)

End Class
```

It then, has this webmethod:

```
<WebMethod(Description:="Upload records to the application database.")>
Public Function WholeDataUpload(ByVal appId As Integer, ByVal TablesData As List(Of DataSyncTransport), ByVal token As String) As String

    Dim _result As String = String.Empty

    For Each item As DataSyncTransport In TablesData

    Next

    'Try
    '    'Get database connection string according the appId provided.
    '    Dim appConnStr As String = getDbConnStr(appId)
    '    _result = UploadData(appConnStr, tableName, idCol, info)

    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    _result = ex.Message

    'End Try

    Return _result

End Function
```

Then, at the client, I don't find any other way to pass that array of custom objects than to write the same class in the client. This mean, I have two "DataSyncTransport" classes, in both, the web service and the client. This sounds bad, but I can't find a workaround for this.

Then, when I try to call the webservice passing an array of DataSyncTransport like this ("ws" is the web service reference):

```
result = ws.WholeDataUpload(10, CompleteDataTransport.ToArray(), AttachmentHelper.Authenticate("12345678"))
```

It throws me the error: "Value of type 'DataSyncTransport()' cannot be converted to 'DataSyncTransport()' because 'DataSyncTransport' is not derived from 'DataSyncTransport'"

The error has to be something with the duplicated classes.

Which is the workaround for this?????

Thank you!

Comment: Create a separate .DLL with the class defined once, and have both the client and the backed reference this .DLL.

Answer (score 0):

are your objects in the array marked with the  [Serializable]  annotation?
 [Serializable] 
public class something

end Class

Comment: Which is the correct syntax in Visual Basic to write the [Serializable] annotation? Writing it as [Serializable] or (Serializable) throws an error.

Comment: <Serializable()> _
    Public Class MyClass


    End Class